# how to paginate in Elastic Search Autocomplete (search as you type in index time)

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, full-text-search

I am facing a road-block in elastic search **autocomplete** feature.

I am using custom analyser to a autocomplete field & it is working like a charm as expected .
Now I want to paginate the result so that my client (angular app) does not need to deal with high volume of data .
Precisely , user types "MATH" I will show first ten relevant results sort by score , then if load-more option is there then user can click that & I will fetch next ten results & so on.

Did not get useful solutions for the above. I don't want to go to **search as you type in query time** (that will be my last approach if nothing works out) .

I am using elastic search 5.6.4 version.
Any concerns/ideas will be highly appreciated.

Comment: each result comes with the hits count and you can use the from /size parameters to control pagination? like from: 0 / size : 10 for the first hit and then based on the total hits /10 you get number of pages . to calculate the from for the subsequent queries simply from = page_number x size;

Comment: elastc search autocomplete suggest parameter does not support from parameter as per my knowledge because form is a low level query not suitable for full text search. Am i missing something?